# Creating local project and checking out desired modules from SVN in IntelliJ

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I am very new to IntelliJ and to this project.
I need to be able to debug applications in IntelliJ with Tomcat and commit changes in subversion.

Do I need to created a local project and then checkout desired modules from SVN?

I am not sure how that works. And in the subversion I would like to checkout the entire folder somewhere and somewhere I would like to checkout only trunk of the directory.

How is this done?

I am also trying to find the way to make these folders dependent on each other since some of them are erroring out not being able to find packages that are in other folders. And when I try to add dependencies, it says "Found no modules to depend on"

Comment: Ideally if you check out `trunk` then you won't need to check out the modules individually - you are hopefully checking out a project which includes all the modules you need. VCS -> Check out from version control is the start point. You shouldn't need to create a local project first, just do a checkout and then "open" the project that you checked out. Can you please try that and come back with more information.

Comment: @vikingsteve I tried checking out the entire project and it was doing it for a while, but then it failed with following message (I had this happen before): Cannot checkout from svn: svn: E204899: Cannot create new file 'C:\Users\iangelina\Desktop\daps\Project Management\Monthly Reports \.svn\lock': The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: @vikingsteve you said if I check out trunk... the project in subversion has many subfolders and each one contains: branch, trunk, tag. What did you mean when you said if I check out trunk? which trunk?

Comment: Can I delete Project Management from within IntelliJ's subversion and try checking out the entire project minus project Management? this would not actually delete Project Management from subversion will it?